# Converting a Probability constraint to a Norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, convex-analysis

Let $\mathbf{z}$ be a $N\times 1$ complex vector. Let $\mathbf{u}$ be a $N\times 1$ random Gaussian vector whose entries are i.i.d with zero mean and $\sigma^2$ variance. Consider the following probability constraint
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Pr}\{~~\lvert\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{u}\rvert^2\geq\gamma~~\} \geq 1-\delta
\end{align} 
where $0\leq \delta <1$. Here, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are given.  Is it possible to convert it into something like
\begin{align}
\lvert\lvert\mathbf{z}\rvert\rvert_2^2\leq f(\gamma,\delta)
\end{align}
where $f(\gamma,\delta)$ depends on $\gamma$ and $\delta$. Here $\mathbf{z}^H$,$\lvert\lvert\mathbf{z}\rvert\rvert_2^2$ denotes conjugate transpose and squared 2-norm of $\mathbf{z}$ respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look for [affine transformation of normal distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation). This tells you that $z^H \, u$ is again normally distributed. From here you can finish. However, you will end up with something like
$$\|z\|_2^2 \ge f(\gamma, \delta),$$
which is a non-convex constraint.

Comment: Can you please show the details, non-convexity is fine.

Comment: Where is the problem?